# Empty spaces in file name -- testing and static analysis

Tags: test-design, static-analysis

Many -- especially older -- programs have or have had the problem that they could not be run in a directory with spaces (e. g. "C:/Program Files/xy"), but requested to be installed directly under C: (e. g. CPython had this problem.). Often, it was not the whole program that crashed, but only some workflows.

Are there common strategies to test on these errors other than to install it in a folder whose path contains spaces and run the test suite (hoping that there is a test suite shipped with)?

Are there any static analysis tools to search for dangerous statements possibly causing this problem? A *very* gullible approach would look for string concatenations of strings containing a batch command and C:. Or to use "C:" hardcoded while not using environment variables. (Yes, it's really bad.)